# How does Android tracks data usage per application?

Tags: android, network-programming, iptables, netfilter

Android can track how may bytes were send and received from/to application. 
I want to know how this data is counted. For example when I run native application, open the TCP socket, send and receive data, this data is accounted.
 I know it has something to do with `xt_qtaguid` module, that tags sockets per UID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick hunt:

From a quick look in packages/apps/Settings (http://androidxref.com/5.1.1_r6/xref/packages/apps/Settings/src/com/android/settings/DataUsageSummary.java#296) it seems it relies on the

NetworkStatsService:
http://androidxref.com/5.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/net/NetworkStatsService.java#906

Which seems to boil down to reading from:

```
mStatsXtIfaceAll = new File(procRoot, "net/xt_qtaguid/iface_stat_all");
mStatsXtIfaceFmt = new File(procRoot, "net/xt_qtaguid/iface_stat_fmt");
mStatsXtUid = new File(procRoot, "net/xt_qtaguid/stats");
```

"net/xt_qtaguid/stats" seems to contain information on app level.

--
Skipping a few steps here, but after this file is only opened for reading, it's written by the xt_qtaguid kernel module.

Code for that:
https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common/+/f0cfc3cc16a15c41107e83f49b61fe2e5a5303be/net/netfilter/xt_qtaguid.c

Kernel is not my expertise, and we're outside of the "Android" part of the System now, perhaps this question belongs as a Linux Kernel question instead of an Android question? :)